# Extract specific portions in html file using python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, extract

How can I extract a specific portion of a html file example https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1208209A1/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry

So far  I used beautifulsoup to get the text version of the html without all the tags. But I would like my code to read only say the claims sections of the above mentioned file.

Comment: Show us the code you already have and tell us what problems you are facing to find the section!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have mate, i found out that in this site, the claims section is a html  with its own Id, making things easier. I just colected the section and gave the string so you can play with it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1208209A1/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
claim_sect = soup.find_all('section', attrs={"itemprop":"claims"})
print('This is the raw content: \n') 
print(str(claim_sect)) 
print('This is the variable type: \n') 
print(str(type(claim_sect))) 
str_sect  =  claim_sect[0]
```

Comment: ` 
---> 22     str_sect  =  claim_section[0]
     
IndexError: list index out of range` What does this code error mean? I get this for few patents

Comment: I have a folder of patents year wise. The code worked for all folders except two. Even though a quick scan through individual patents show there is a claim section , the code returns index out of range for str_sect=claim_sect[0]. What exactly is this claim_sect[0] indicating?

Comment: To understand this line, you must understand one line above. This:
claim_sect = soup.find_all('section', attrs={"itemprop":"claims"})

What is this doing?
I have a object called soup, which contains the whole HTML code, then I create a new variable called claim_sect, which will receive every element that matches with the criteria that I passed (it is inside html <section> and have a id called'claims'.)

The thing is that this could return multiple values, so it returns a list of values.
In the last line I want the first element from this list, that's why I use claim_sect[0]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and this helps me understand the line. Is there like a way I could find out what are the lists its generating so I can debug why those patents don't return the claims section?

Comment: Sure there is, try this code and tell me the console output (also after some weeks using python, I highly suggest you to move to something like visual studio code+python extension and study about python debugging with code, your life will change trust me :) )

Comment: I ran it through a folder and got an output for the type as <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>

Comment: I opened the files and found few patents did not have claims section and hence the error. Thank you very much for helping me sort this issue systematically. I will definitely move to visual studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770541/extract-a-specific-header-from-html-using-beautiful-soup?noredirect=1#comment112767976_63770541     Could you help me with code

Comment: @RoniAntonio thanks. How would the code be, to include in the claim_sect more than one section, not only id called 'claims' but more ids. I am working with research articles, and want to include the abstract, methods, results and conclusion sections in one variable. This is so that the rest of my code works with these sections only, and excludes things like the references. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @HR123r notice how in the last line I use claim_sect[0]? 
This is because i forcely choose the first element of the python list. Potentially, when you do web scrap, you return multiple elements, just like your case.

Comment: On this case, you need a for each structure. Something like:

for item in claim_sect:
    methods = item['your stuff']
    results = item['another stuff']
    conclusion  = item['another stuff']


I highly recommend you do this on a python controlled environment where you can debug line by line to see the things happening. Good luck!

Comment: @RoniAntonio thanks for your response. What do you mean 
conclusion = item['another stuff]
In my case, I work with research articles (such as this one: https://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2164-14-728).The sections are like <section data-title="Background"> The conclusion would be <section data-title="Conclusions">. You see it changes each time. The other issues I think I might encounter, is how different publishers, might be using different HTML section names, so writing code based on the structure of one paper only, might not be scalable and universal for all papers

Comment: Post this question as a new question, I will be glad to answer. I can't put formatted code here

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, there are two divs with the class="flex flex-width style-scope patent-result".

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "flex flex-width style-scope patent-result"})
div_with_claims = mydivs [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename= 'C:/Users/xyz/.ipynb_checkpoints/EP1208209A1.html'
html_file =open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = html_file.read() 
#print(source_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
print(soup.get_text())
#mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "flex flex-width style-scope patent-result"})
#div_with_claims = mydivs [1]
#print(div_with_claims)
```