# Extract a specific header from HTML using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, extract

This is the patent example I am using https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1208209A1/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry . Below is the code I used. I want the code to display only the cited by (3) count so I know how many times this patent was cited.How can I get the output to display the cited by count as 3 only? Kindly help!

`````
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(patent, 'html.parser')
cited_section =soup.findAll({"h2":"Cited By"})

print(cited_section)
Output I get is [<h2>Info</h2>, <h2>Links</h2>, <h2>Images</h2>, <h2>Classifications</h2>, <h2>Abstract</h2>, <h2>Description</h2>, <h2>Claims (<span itemprop="count">57</span>)</h2>, <h2>Priority Applications (5)</h2>, <h2>Applications Claiming Priority (1)</h2>, <h2>Related Parent Applications (1)</h2>, <h2>Publications (2)</h2>, <h2>ID=38925605</h2>, <h2>Family Applications (1)</h2>, <h2>Country Status (1)</h2>, <h2>Cited By (3)</h2>, <h2>Families Citing this family (12)</h2>, <h2>Citations (306)</h2>, <h2>Patent Citations (348)</h2>, <h2>Non-Patent Citations (23)</h2>, <h2>Cited By (4)</h2>, <h2>Also Published As</h2>, <h2>Similar Documents</h2>, <h2>Legal Events</h2>]````
`````

Comment: It seems that the page is asynchronously rendered. I suggest you use `Selenium`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of citations is created dynamically via JavaScript. But you can count number of elements with `itemprop="forwardReferencesFamily"` to get the count. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1208209A1/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(len(soup.select('tr[itemprop="forwardReferencesFamily"]')))
```

Prints:

```
4
```

Comment: Hi following the same topic in the html file I would like to find just the patent number, title of the citations from the HTML tag. I tried this but it prints all the titles in the HTML file. 
```html_file =open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') # Opening file in read mode
patent = html_file.read() 
#print(patent)
total=0
soup = BeautifulSoup(patent, 'html.parser')

x=soup.select('tr[itemprop="backwardReferences"]')
 
y=soup.select('td[itemprop="title"]')
print(y)```

Comment: @astronaut I'd suggest to open a new question here on SO where you describe the problem + what have you tried. I'd try to look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270690/extract-information-from-html-tags-into-pandas/67274030?noredirect=1#comment118915500_67274030  this it the new discussion. I tried your approach of taking the HTML tag 'tr[itemprop="backwardReferencesFamily"]' but I could not get it to print only title and publication number under this tag. and I think that is the only common HTML tag among all patent. Anything else may not be a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in this link https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2012061469A3/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry I want the code to print the patent citations  which should give publication number, title. I then want to use pandas to put publication number in a column and the title in another column.
so far I have used beautiful soup to convert the HTML file into a readable format.I have selected backward references HTML tag and under that I want it to print the publication number and title of the citations. I am citing one single example, but I have a folder full of HTML files which I will do later.

```
x=soup.select('tr[itemprop="backwardReferences"]') 
y=soup.select('td[itemprop="title"]') # this line gives all the titles in the document not particularly under the patent citations
print(y)
```